# DC Motor temperature

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

Im running a 18v Cordless drill motor (probably a RS 555 i dont have any info as it only says Black and decker LD120) with a bts 7960 and 12v ATX Power supply.

I have used it for my purpose for like 2 hours straight and its surface feels just a little bit warm, obviously i dont want it to fry so better to ask before than after.

Is there any optimal temperature? maybe hotter is better?

Whats the normal maximum temperature for a DC Motor of this type? i've used drills and i know they get really hot and last years.

Is worse (temps, efficiency, power, torque , etc) that i am running it with less voltage than it is rated? It comes with a 20v Battery but i've searched in some chinese manufacturer pages and identical ones are rated 12-18 12-20v and like that.

Answer (score 1):

The snide answer is "ask Black and Decker", but they're not going to give you information on that. Motors are usually rated for continuous or intermittent duty, which a drill is pretty intermittent. I'm sure you saw a fan impeller somewhere when you were disassembling the drill to get at the motor; you might consider adding one back in. "A bit warm" sounds fine; you're probably running it at a low fraction of its max torque, but obviously if this is a critical application, then spend the money and get a motor rated for continuous duty.

Comment: Thanks for your response, about voltage and current, wouldn't it be better if i supplied more as in my application it has some intermittent power output which activates the fans inside, right now im supplying about 60w Maximum and motor spins fast but not as nearly as it can and fans goes with it. what do you think.

https://www.amazon.com/RS-550s-18v-Electronic-Controlled-Replacement/dp/B00TE42PME.
This looks exactly like my motor and it seems rated for 180w , i saw that when it spins faster and fans too, motor outputs more power but doesnt get much hotter and thats what im looking for.